# Reclaim unallocated disk space on macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, partition, third-party

I had portioned my hard drive into two (mac and Windows). Later I portioned the primary (mac) into two but figure my Windows were not loading so I changed it back into one. The problem is there is about 600MB of unallocated space that I can't seem to merge with the primary. Is there any way to god it. Mac Disk Utility can't even see it! Screenshot is below
[image]

When I load into Windows, fdisk shows unallocated space. I did try to drag the partition handles to maximum, but that has not solved the problem.

How can I reclaim this unallocated hard disk space?

Comment: Are you sure the space is really free? I wouldn't trust `fdisk` to accurately show a hybrid GPT/MBR partition setup... You might try enabling [Disk Utility's Debug menu](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Enable-Disk-Utilitys-Debug-Menu.htm), then enabling "Show Every Partition" to see the things it normally hides.

Comment: You are probably right. Let me try that. I have another question about GPT/MBR, I will probably ask that too.

Comment: Try running diskutil list